# Nested Recursive Function Flow in Python

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

While working through a better than brute force solution for Euler problem 37, I came across a nested recursive algorithm that was very efficient. Unfortunately, I'm unable to fully understand the logic flow. Below is a similar nested function stripped to the core concept.

```
def print_func(n):
    print(n)

def nest_func(n):
    print_func(n)
    for cntn in range(1,6):
        n = n * 10 + cntn
        if n < 1000: nest_func(n)

for cnt in range(1,6):
    nest_func(cnt)
```

The debug output is:

```
1
11
111
112
2
21
211
212
3
... to 512
```

I don't understand why the debug output is not:

```
1
11
111
112
113
114
115
12
121
122
123
124
125
13
...to 555
```

Any help understanding this or keywords to better help search for references would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the fact that `n` is shared variable inside the recursion. If you write `n = n * 10 + cntn`, you update the `n` each time.

Lets change the code a little bit, as the following.

```
def print_func(n):
    print(n)

def nest_func(n):
    print_func(n)
    for cntn in range(1,6):
        a = n * 10 + cntn
        if a < 1000: nest_func(a)

for cnt in range(1,3):
    nest_func(cnt)
```

Now, the output should be what you expected. (Or `nest_func(n * 10 + cntn)`)

---

Your misunderstanding is that `n` in each `nest_func` are not in same scope. But no, that's not what recursion want. If `n` is localized for each `nest_func`, recursion lose its meaning.

Comment: Thank you! You're absolutely correct, I assumed that the functions keep within their own scope even though n was created before then next layer which would be shared. I just couldn't wrap my head around what was happening.

Answer (score 0):

```py
# 自己写出执行过程即可明白
# You can understand by writing the execution process yourself
def nest_func(n):
    print_func(n) #1
    for cntn in range(1,6):#n=1
        n = n * 10 + cntn#n=11
        if n < 1000: nest_func(n)#n=11

def nest_func(n):#n=11 这是第一次递归 This is the first recursion
    print_func(n) #11 返回输出112 returns output 112
    for cntn in range(1,6):#n=11
        n = n * 10 + cntn#n=111  #n=112
        if n < 1000: nest_func(n)#n=111

def nest_func(n):#n=111 这是第二次递归 This is the second recursion
    print_func(n) #111
    for cntn in range(1,6):#n=111 到这里就不再往下执行 No longer execute down here
        n = n * 10 + cntn#n=1110
        if n < 1000: nest_func(n)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your answer and format the code using [Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Furthermore, please translate your response into English, so that others may benefit from it. You may want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer in the meanwhile